# How to get distinct values from aggregate method in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select the shortest and longest name, and if there is more than one name with the same length, I should get the first one ordered by the name

For example if I have these values:

```
'abc', 'def', 'abcd', 'defghi', 'ghi'
```

I should get something like

```
abc    3
defghi 6
```

This is my query

```
select 
    Name, LEN(Name)
from 
    Customer
where 
    len(Name) = (select min(len(Name)) from Customer)
    or
    len(Name) = (select max(len(Name)) from Customer)
order by
    Name;
```

but here is what I get

```
abc    3
def    3
defghi 6
ghi    3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is easiest as a `union all` with `top`:

```
select *
from ((select top 1 c.*
       from customer
       order by len(name) desc, name
      ) union all
      (select top 1 c.*
       from customer
       order by len(name) asc, name
      )
     ) t;
```

Comment: I believe this is the correct approach, but is not valid SQL Server syntax, all derived tables require an alias, and you would need an outer select too, since even when the subqueries have an alias this fails.

Answer (score 1):

With window functions:

```
with cte as(select *, 
                   row_number() over(order by len(name), name) rn1,
                   row_number() over(order by len(name) desc, name) rn2
            from Customer)
select name, len(name) from cte where rn1 = 1 or rn2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order them by length and name like:

```
declare @data table(name varchar(10))
insert into @data(name) values('abc'), ('def'), ('abcd'), ('defghi'), ('ghi')

Select name From (
    Select *
        , small = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by len(name), name)
        , big = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by len(name) desc, name)
    From @data
) t
Where small = 1 or big = 1
```